# Received fatal alert: protocol_version build failure Gradle/Maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, java-8, java-7

One of my project's build started failing with the exception given below

```
   > Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:[1.6.1,).
  > Failed to list versions for org.slf4j:slf4j-api.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/maven-metadata.xml'.
           > Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

**Environment:**

- Java 7
- Gradle 3.5

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maven Central and Bintray have announced that they will discontinue support for TLS v1.1 and below.
You will be affected if you are using Java 6 or 7 and using Gradle versions 2.1 through 4.8.

## GRADLE:

Check gradle version

```
gradle --version
```

You must take action if all of these are true:

- JVM version is Java 7u130 or lower and
- Gradle version is between 2.1 and 4.8, inclusive
- and you have declared a repository {} of mavenCentral() or jcenter()

You can take any one of the following actions to use TLS v1.2+:

- Run Gradle with Java 1.7.0_131-b31 or above
- or upgrade to Gradle 4.8.1 or above
- or replace mavenCentral() with maven { url =
  "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" } and jcenter() with maven {
  url = "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }

The first two solutions are recommended, as the third opens a possible attack vector.

Source:https://blog.gradle.org

## Maven:


If you are using **Maven** use the command given below

```
mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 install
```

Comment: IBM JDK 1.8.0 has the same problem. I don't remember installing it, but somehow it got set as my default Java. I changed the default back to Oracle JDK 1.8.0 and now Gradle is working again.

Comment: What about Visual Studio Cordova apps? I get the same error, but it explicitly requires Gradle 2.1.0. I tried 4.8.1, but it wouldn't accept it.

Comment: try using maven {
           url 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
           name 'Maven Central'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com'
            name 'JCenter'
        }
    instead of mavenCentral() and jcenter().

Comment: USAGE: <gradle version>
Following arguments are required: <gradle-version>

Answer (score 0):

If you have similar problem with pom.xml - just update maven-compiler-plugin source and target version to 1.8, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**IBM JDK**

if you are using IBM IDK you need to set following JVM argument.

```
com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultProtocol=SSL_TLSv2.
```

Refer the IBM documentation: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/overrideSSLprotocol.html

So, in eclipse IDE,

Open 'Run->Run Configurations'; expand 'Gradle Project' and select the run configuration ( build )

set the JVM argument as follows
[set jvm argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV6Gz.png)

Comment: also,  if you see this issue in eclipse /STS   edit eclipse.ini or sts.ini and provide jvm parameter -Dhttp.protocols=TLSv1.2